# org-roam + ox-hugo exporting results in broken links

Tags: org-mode, org-roam, hugo

I've been following [this setup](https://github.com/jethrokuan/braindump) to export my org-roam notes with ox-hugo, but I get the following kind of errors when exporting.

```
ERROR 2022/01/03 09:27:37 [en] REF_NOT_FOUND: Ref "../../../../../data/Documents/rnotes/org/20211206181129-sdn_vs_nfv.md": "/home/eros/Documents/rnotes/hugo/content/posts/20211206162106-software_defined_networking.md:29:18": page not found
```

Indeed I can see that in the .md file the link is exported as follows

```
+++
title = "SDN vs NFV"
draft = false
+++

While both [SDN]({{<relref "../../../../../data/Documents/rnotes/org/20211206162106-software_defined_networking.md#" >}})
```

While I would expect something similar to this (from [here](https://github.com/jethrokuan/braindump/blob/master/content/posts/arguments_against_bayesian_inference.md)), since all the .md files are actually stored in the same folder.

```
+++
title = "Arguments Against Bayesian Inference"
author = ["Jethro Kuan"]
draft = false
+++

tags
: [Bayesian Inference]({{<relref "bayesian_inference.md#" >}})
```

I'm using the same `config.toml` as [this one](https://github.com/jethrokuan/braindump/blob/master/config.toml), except I've set the baseURL to `localhost`

My `publish.el`

```
(require 'package)

(package-initialize)

(setq package-archives '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")
                         ("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/")))

(require 'find-lisp)
(require 'ox-hugo)

(defun roam-publish (file)
  (with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect file)
    (setq org-hugo-base-dir "../hugo")
    (let ((org-id-extra-files (find-lisp-find-files "." "\.org$")))
      (org-hugo-export-wim-to-md))))
```

And the `build.py`calling it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
from pathlib import Path

files = glob.glob("org/*.org")

with open('build.ninja', 'w') as ninja_file:
    ninja_file.write("""
rule org2md
  command = emacs --batch -l publish.el --eval \"(roam-publish \\"$in\\")"
  description = org2md $inxb
""")
    
    for f in files:
        path = Path(f)
        output_file = f"hugo/content/posts/{path.with_suffix('.md').name}"
        ninja_file.write(f"""
build {output_file}: org2md {path}
""")

import subprocess
subprocess.call(["ninja"])
```

Comment: Can you open an issue on https://github.com/kaushalmodi/ox-hugo with a minimum reproducible example containing the 2 Org files?

Comment: Sure, I've just opened one here https://github.com/kaushalmodi/ox-hugo/issues/500.